# Why is the distance between Boulder and Philadelphia is 7 miles? Am I doing my math wrong?

Tags: math, geolocation, geospatial

This is the lat/long for Philadelphia: http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/tools/coordinates.aspx?nav=11&c=DD&md=24&mdt=International(1924)-Hayford(1909)&lat=39.947648&lath=N&lon=-75.151978&lonh=W

This is the lat/long for Boulder: http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/tools/coordinates.aspx?nav=11&c=DD&md=24&mdt=International(1924)-Hayford(1909)&lat=40.0149856&lath=N&lon=-105.2705456&lonh=W

That lat and long are correct (You can check it in Google Maps).  UTM_east and UTM_north are also correct for both.

Now, plug the UTMs into the distance formula here: http://www.basic-mathematics.com/distance-formula-calculator.html

And you will get distance in meters, which is 7 miles.

Why on earth is Boulder 7 miles away from Philadelphia?

Comment: I see the Python tag, but what does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that a wormhole (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) exists between the two cities?

Comment: Oh, I got it.  Cleveland is between them.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just plug in the UTM coordinates like that because these two cities are not in the same [UTM Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#UTM_zone).

EDIT:

And, as everyone else has pointed out, even if they were in the same zone, you shouldn't just apply a planar, cartesian distance calculation to the UTM coordinates because the UTM coordinates are based on a cylindrical projection. I was just pointing out that the largest contributing factor to your error was the zone issue.

Comment: And even if they were, using cartesian distance in a UTM zone still won't give you a correct answer as that projection isn't good enough for that type of calculation. You will need to use an angular method, like suggested in other comments.

Comment: @Niklas: Also very true. However, the errors you get between spherical vs. planar coordinates are usually not of this magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude are a spherical coordinate system and the formula you're using only works on a plane. You need to use the [haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: @TIMEX Probably because UTMs are on different grids. You would have to add in the missing grids. Sorry I've never used UTM before.

Answer (score 0):

When I calculate the distance between the two points as if they were on a standard Cartesian plane, I get a distance of 29.9, which is really close to the tool's result:

> The distance between these two points is 29.900202340452488

First, using a Cartesian distance calculator on a spherical object isn't going to give good results. :) (Leaving aside that the Earth isn't spherical, but it sure isn't flat either.)

**BUT**, let's assume for a second that using Cartesian distance is "good enough", the results here are measured in whatever units we input. And knowing that [1 degree is roughly 111 km](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217348/how-do-i-convert-kilometres-to-degrees-in-geodjango-geos/5218719#5218719), we get a quick guess that the distance between Boulder and Philadelphia is roughly `3318.9 km`. Given that Google's driving directions between the two is roughly `2841 km`, you can immediately see why applying Cartesian distance algorithms won't work on a sphere, and why you need to use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: Probably the best UTM can do is _approximate_ flat for small 6 degree x 6 degree sections of the sphere. Whether or not this approximation is "good enough" depends upon how the data is used: driving distances, fine, but I wouldn't want to use it for artillery tables or autopilot landing systems.