# How to convert Kilometer to Latitude Longitude degrees in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

I want to convert km to Latitude Longitude degrees in javascript.

I did not come across any thing as how to do that.

Any help will be much helpful.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question... Kilometres are a measure of distance, whereas degrees are a measure of temperature... they can't be converted...

Comment: Degrees also measure lattitude and longitude, **but** it's not simple to convert, as it depends where you are

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: degrees are also measure of angle. Maybe the OP means some geo-related transformations

Comment: See http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to understand how big a question this is ;)

Comment: @ChrisBallard I did consider that possibility, but as you say it's not easy! If you're 1/2πkm from the North Pole, then 1km East is a full 360 degrees!

Comment: Exactly. Heading north/south you can make an assumption about the circumference of the earth and do the calc trivially, but east/west it depends how far above/below the equator you are

Comment: A minute (1/60th of a degree) equals 1.852 km

Comment: @Tasos only on a line which is the full circumference of the earth - so the equator, or a line of longitude. Otherwise each degree represents less and less as you head away from the equator, converging on zero at the poles.

Comment: At the equator, the circumference of the earth is 24,902 miles, or 40,076 km. 

There are 360 degrees in a circle, and on the earth, so: 

40076 / 360 = 111.32 km/degree (the accepted figure is 111.325 km).

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217348/how-do-i-convert-kilometres-to-degrees-in-geodjango-geos

Comment: beside the question has any sense to convert distance to coordinates, this is not a programming question, not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly then you may use this formula:

```
1 minute of latitude North to south = 1 Nautical Mile 
1 Nautical Mile = 6075 feet 
1 degree = 60 Minutes
60 minutes = 60 * 6075 feet 
1 meter =3.28 Feet 
Hence 1 degree = 60 * 6075 / 3.28 Meters = 111,128 meters
And 1 kilometer = 1000 meters.

1 minute of Latitude = 1,852 Meters
1 degree = 60 * 1852 meters = 111.120 kilometers
```

So now you can do the conversions as you want.(*Although degree in your question was confusing initially)*

Also check **[Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)** - this states that *for a great circle route* the above applies. Beware that if not travelling a great circle route, degrees of latitude get closer together the further you are from the equator (the distance becomes zero at the poles).

Comment: See my comment. This **only** works on the equator heading east/west or if heading directly north/south

Comment: @ChrisBallard:- This was not specified in the question. I just provided the answer and calculation involved for the conversion.

Comment: @Teemu:- I have provided the other way round. Please check the math again! :)

Comment: The result seems to be the same... Not my downvote though.

Comment: Added my caveat and removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do conversions between geographical coordinate systems and (geodesic) distances, the best approach is probably to use a third-party library, as it is an involved subject once you progress beyond the spherical earth approximation. I have used the Javascript OpenLayers mapping library to make similar calculations in the oppopsite direction (lat/Lon pairs to distances). Take a look at the appropriate parts of the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Curve-js.html) for guidance