# GeoDjango: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries

Tags: django, gis, geospatial, geodjango

I'm trying to get N points within 5000 meters of a certain point. My database is Postgres(PostGis). I have a model like this:

```
class Theatre(models.Model):
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Then I ran a couple lines in django shell:

> > > Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(30.111199 -97.309990)'), D(m=5000)))

and I get error:

```
ValueError: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries.
```

I found the document in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries) and it says calculating the geometry distance..

Please help.. Thanks very much!!

Comment: You need a comma between the two decimal numbers in y our POINT()?

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl like this: `Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('Point(30.111199,-97.309990)'),D(m=5000)))`? give me error: `GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKTReader_read_r".`  Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, clearly that is not it :(

Answer (score 1):

A *little* late to the party, but...

According to [Django's source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py#L280) this error will be raised if using PostGIS and the field you are querying against is "geodetic" (its SRID corresponds with a coordinate system that uses non-projected units (e.g., latitude/longitude) [(definition from the docs)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py#L133) -- in which case you need to pass a numeric value of degree units instead of the `D` object, as indicated by the error message.

This is unfortunately not a simple conversion depending on the distance from the equator; see [How do I convert kilometres to degrees in Geodjango/GEOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217427/284164)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you x and y values in the [POINT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.Point) WKT are reversed.

Try:

```
Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(-97.309990 30.111199)'), D(m=5000)))
```